# A First Look At Rigorous Probability Theory - Jeffrey Rosenthal Exercise 4.5.10

Tags: probability-theory

In the exercise, it says :

"Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and let $N$ be an integer-valued random variable with mean $m$ and variance $\nu$, with $N$ independent of all the $X_i$. Let $S=X_1+...+X_N=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\mathbb{1}_{N\geq i}$. Compute $Var(S)$ in terms of $\mu,\sigma^2,m,\nu$."

Is the question saying that $N$ is a constant or that its values are integers? Also, I'm a bit confused about this part:  $S=X_1+...+X_N=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\mathbb{1}_{N\geq i}$. Why is it that $X_1+...+X_N=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\mathbb{1}_{N\geq i}$? Is it just a notation?

Comment: $N$ is random variable which takes integer values. It is not a constant. In the infinite sum the terms corresponding to $i >N$ are all $0$ so the infinite sum reduces to the sum from $i=1$ to $i=N$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I get that the terms corresponding to i > N are all 0 in the infinite sum, but what does it mean for the sum to be reduced from i=1 to i=N, when N is a random variable?

Comment: For each fixed $\omega$ in the sample space $N(\omega)$ is just an integer constant.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. Thank you!